# how to create class in android and call DatabaseHelper

Tags: android

I want to call the method in the Other class, but I get the error on this line:

```
dbh=new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
```

Error message:

> "The method getApplicationContext() is undefined for the type add_point"

Comment: where do you call that line? In which method/class

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to use that helper in some non `activity` classes, I would suggest you pass the `Context` once with a setter or a specific constructor and make your Helper static. **Non Activity/Service** class aren't aware of the `applicationContext`.

```
private static Context context;

public static void setContext(Context context){
    DatabaseHelper.context = context;
}
```

You could also use the `Singleton` pattern in order to have one single instance of the helper.

Answer (score 0):

i have class databsehelper  , but call the methode in new class show errore.

```
public class add_point extends TestCase   {
SQLiteDatabase db;
DatabaseHelper dbh;

final long ONE_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000L;
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

Hijri hij= new Hijri();
Monasebat mon=new Monasebat();
JalaliCalendar jl=new JalaliCalendar();
String event;

Date today = new Date();
dateConvert_Shamsi dshamsi =new  dateConvert_Shamsi();



String text;
String DateFirst= "03/20/2016";
String DateEnde= "04/22/2016";
String df="03/20/2016";
String ef="04/22/2016";//42";
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private ProgressBar bar;



    public  void start2()
    {
        dbh=new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext()); 
            //dbh=new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());

        for(int i=0;i<13;i++)
        {
            try
            {
            switch (i) {
            case 1:
                getDatesBetween("03/20/2016","04/22/2016","tbl_Addshift_"+String.valueOf(i),"روزکار","روزکار","روزکار","روزکار","روزکار","روزکار","روزکار");
            break;
            case 2:
                getDatesBetween("03/20/2016","04/22/2016","tbl_Addshift_"+String.valueOf(i),"فولادمبارکه","شیفت","A","روزکار","شب کار","استراحت اول","استراحت دوم");
            break;
            case 3:
                getDatesBetween("03/20/2016","04/22/2016","tbl_Addshift_"+String.valueOf(i),"فولادمبارکه","شیفت","B","استراحت اول","استراحت دوم","روزکار","شب کار");
            break;
            case 4:
                getDatesBetween("03/20/2016","04/22/2016","tbl_Addshift_"+String.valueOf(i),"فولادمبارکه","شیفت","C","شب کار","استراحت اول","استراحت دوم","روزکار");
            break;
            case 5:
                getDatesBetween("03/20/2016","04/22/2016","tbl_Addshift_"+String.valueOf(i),"فولادمبارکه","شیفت","D","استراحت دوم","روزکار","شب کار","استراحت اول");
            break;

            case 6:
                //getDatesBetween(Dat"04/22/2016"irst,DateEnde,"tbl_Addshift_"+String.valueOf(i),"فولادمبارکه","شیفت","نوبت کار","شیفت","شب کار","استراحت اول","استراحت دوم");
            break;

            /*case 7:
                getDatesBetween("03/20/2016",ef,"tbl_Addshift_"+String.valueOf(i),"ذوب آهن","روزکار","روزکار","روزکار","روزکار","روزکار","روزکار");
            break;*/
            case 7:
                getDatesBetween("03/20/2016","04/22/2016","tbl_Addshift_"+String.valueOf(i),"ذوب آهن","شیفت","1","روزکار","شب کار","استراحت اول","استراحت دوم");
            break;
            case 8:
                getDatesBetween("03/20/2016","04/22/2016","tbl_Addshift_"+String.valueOf(i),"ذوب آهن","شیفت","2","روزکار","شب کار","استراحت اول","استراحت دوم");
            break;
            case 9:
                getDatesBetween("03/20/2016","04/22/2016","tbl_Addshift_"+String.valueOf(i),"ذوب آهن","شیفت","3","روزکار","شب کار","استراحت اول","استراحت دوم");
            break;
            case 10:
                getDatesBetween("03/20/2016","04/22/2016","tbl_Addshift_"+String.valueOf(i),"ذوب آهن","شیفت","4","روزکار","شب کار","استراحت اول","استراحت دوم");
            break;
            case 11:
                getDatesBetween("03/20/2016","04/22/2016","tbl_Addshift_"+String.valueOf(i),"فولادمبارکه","شیفت","1نوبت کار","روزکار","شب کار","استراحت اول","استراحت دوم");
            break;
            case 12:
                getDatesBetween("03/20/2016","04/22/2016","tbl_Addshift_"+String.valueOf(i),"فولادمبارکه","شیفت","2نوبت کار","روزکار","شب کار","استراحت اول","استراحت دوم");
            break;
            case 13:
                getDatesBetween("03/20/2016","04/22/2016","tbl_Addshift_"+String.valueOf(i),"روزکار","روزکار","روزکار","روزکار","روزکار","روزکار","روزکار");
            break;
            }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e+"--------------start2--------------");
            }
        }
    }




    public  void getDatesBetween(String startDate,String endDate,String tbl,String nameWork,String typeshift,String nameShift,String day1,String day2,String day3,String day4) {
        dbh=new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        int DayShamsi = 0;
            int MountShamsi;
            int YearShamsi;

            String txt_day_count="";
            //Calendar mydate = Calendar.getInstance();
            String DateJalali;
            String DateJalali2 = null;
            String DateJalali3 = null;
            String datetime="";

        try
        {

            long  from=Date.parse(startDate);  
            long to=Date.parse(endDate);  
        int x=0;
        int cont=1;


        while(from <= to) {
              x=x+1;

              if (cont==1) 
                      {
                  txt_day_count=day1;
                  cont++;
                      }
              else if (cont==2) 
          {
                  txt_day_count=day2;
                  cont++;
          }
              else if(cont==3) 
          {
                  txt_day_count=day3;
                  cont++;
          }
              else if(cont==4) 
          {
                  txt_day_count=day4;
                  cont=1;
          }

              cal.setTime(new Date(from));
              DateJalali=jl.getJalaliDate(new Date(from));

              dshamsi.setGregorianDate(cal.get(cal.YEAR),cal.get(cal.MONTH)+1,cal.get(cal.DAY_OF_MONTH));

              event=mon.JalaliMonasebat(cal.get(cal.MONTH)+1,cal.get(cal.DAY_OF_MONTH));
             hij.miladi(new Date(from));
              DateJalali2=hij.Dayhejri();
              DateJalali3=String.valueOf(hij.JalaliTatil()+"\n"+mon.JalaliTatil());
              int tatile=0;
              int tatileH=0;
              tatile = mon.JalaliTatil();
              tatileH = hij.JalaliTatil();

              dbh.Add_Shift(datetime,String.valueOf(cal.getTime()),
                      nameWork, 
                      typeshift,
                      nameShift,
                        txt_day_count,

                        String.valueOf(dshamsi.getIranianYear()+"-"+dshamsi.getIranianMonth()),//String.valueOf(jl.JalaliYear(cal.getTime()))+"-"+String.valueOf(jl.JalaliMonth(cal.getTime())),//DateJalali3+"-"+DateJalali2,// String.valueOf(YearShamsi+"-"+MountShamsi),
                        String.valueOf(new Date(from)),
                        event+"\n"+DateJalali2,
                        DateJalali3,
                        tbl,
                        String.valueOf(tatile+"-"+tatileH)
                        );
              System.out.println(String.valueOf(new Date(from))+"-----------getDatesBetween-----------------");
              from += ONE_DAY;
        }


        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e+"-----------0000-getDatesBetween---------------- "+"\n"+String.valueOf(datetime+cal.getTime().toString()+"-"+
                      nameWork+"-"+ 
                      typeshift+"-"+
                      nameShift+"-"+
                        txt_day_count+"-"+
                        String.valueOf(dshamsi.getIranianYear()+"-"+dshamsi.getIranianMonth())+"-"+//String.valueOf(jl.JalaliYear(cal.getTime()))+"-"+String.valueOf(jl.JalaliMonth(cal.getTime())),//DateJalali3+"-"+DateJalali2,// String.valueOf(YearShamsi+"-"+MountShamsi),
                        String.valueOf(new Date(startDate))+"-"+
                        event+"\n"+DateJalali2+"-"+
                        DateJalali3+"-"+
                        tbl+
                        String.valueOf("tatile"+"-"+"tatileH")));
        }

    }





    public void add()
    {
        dbh=new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        for(int i=0 ; i<12 ; i++)
        {
            try
            {
            switch (i) {
            case 1:
                dbh.AddRowtable("روزکار","روزکار","روزکار","tbl_Addshift_"+String.valueOf(i));

                break;
            case 2:
                dbh.AddRowtable("فولادمبارکه","شیفت","A","tbl_Addshift_"+String.valueOf(i));
                break;
            case 3:
                dbh.AddRowtable("فولادمبارکه","شیفت","B","tbl_Addshift_"+String.valueOf(i));
                break;
            case 4:
                dbh.AddRowtable("فولادمبارکه","شیفت","C","tbl_Addshift_"+String.valueOf(i));
                break;
            case 5:
                dbh.AddRowtable("فولادمبارکه","شیفت","D","tbl_Addshift_"+String.valueOf(i));
                break;

            case 6:
                dbh.AddRowtable("فولادمبارکه","شیفت","نوبت کار","tbl_Addshift_"+String.valueOf(i));
                break;
            case 7:
                dbh.AddRowtable("ذوب آهن","شیفت","1","tbl_Addshift_"+String.valueOf(i));

                break;
            case 8:
                dbh.AddRowtable("ذوب آهن","شیفت","2","tbl_Addshift_"+String.valueOf(i));
                break;
            case 9:
                dbh.AddRowtable("ذوب آهن","شیفت","3","tbl_Addshift_"+String.valueOf(i));
                break;
            case 10:
                dbh.AddRowtable("ذوب آهن","شیفت","4","tbl_Addshift_"+String.valueOf(i));
                break;
            case 11:
                dbh.AddRowtable("ذوب آهن","نوبت کار","1","tbl_Addshift_"+String.valueOf(i));
                break;
            case 12:
                dbh.AddRowtable("ذوب آهن","نوبت کار","2","tbl_Addshift_"+String.valueOf(i));
                break;



            }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e+"--------------add--------------");
            }
        //dbh.AddRowtable(txt_ID.getText().toString(),   txt_name.getText().toString(), txt_family.getText().toString());


        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If use of Fragment then not support getApplicationContext(), It's use only getActivity().

and else use of Activity Please Refer this Link:

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-sqlite-database-with-multiple-tables/